# DBML file, drag and drop table - overwrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, dynamic-data

Just a general question regarding the `DBML` file in my project.

Say, For e.g my DBML file shows the `r/ships` between 30 tables.  To save me looking through the entire document for a particular table is there any '`quick find`' solutions. I've tried the `CTRL + F` button but it doesn't seem to register with the DBML document.

I've also tried dragging the table onto the document in the hope of receiving some sort of message: 'This table already exists would you like to re-write it', but the table just renames its self from say '`dogs`' to '`dogs1`'.

In short is there some sort of method to finding a particular table, with relative ease?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah it is. Didn't realize...thanks for the reply